# Qcubed button not working?

Tags: xampp, qcubed

I'm using xampp 1.8.1 and Qcubed 2.1.0.. both were installed successfully.
We successfully created database tables in phpmyadmin.

While inserting values through phpmyadmin you can see the records in Qdatagrid
But when we reach the form drafts, the qcubed buttons [save] etc do not work(or respond in any way)!
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Are you receiving any Ajax errors? If not look at the net tab in Firebug or Chrome and look at the response and see if there is an error there.

If this doesn't help try posting some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not give the link of what should happen when the save button is clicked , so nothing is happening.

example :

`$this->btnRefresh = new QButton($this);
        $this->btnRefresh->Text = 'Refresh';
        $this->btnRefresh->AddCssClass("btn-info");
        $this->btnRefresh->AddAction(new QClickEvent(), new QAjaxControlAction($this, 'btnRefresh_click'));`

It will call this function

```
public function btnRefresh_click(){
    // the refresh code goes here
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow; this answer probably should have been a comment, as once the asker fixes their question this answer will be inappropriate.